# New VisualVM 1.3.4 install hangs on "Computing description"

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

I had jVisualVM 1.7.0_03 (from the JDK install) working fine.  I installed the latest VisualVM 1.3.4.  I started it up.  It printed "Computing description" and started the progress dialog.  It's been running for several minutes now.  It's not blocking the UI, but it's also not listing any of the local Java processes.  The jVisualVM from the JDK has no trouble doing this.  I was able to install plugins into this new release, but it's still "Computing description".

Comment: I afterwards tried restarting the old jVisualVM, and it's doing the same thing.  It's consistently taking about 8 minutes (~480 seconds) to start up and display the local processes.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a situation like this.  I moved the visualvm folder to C:\ and updated the proxy settings.  Worked fine after that, ymv.